# Why does this online compiler allow me to compile the code even if the functions are not declared before the main?

Tags: c

online compiler: https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler#

Why does this compiler let me compile a code without the functions before the main function? Shouldn't it be an error?

Comment: What code are you trying to compile?

Comment: @ReticulatedSpline it doesn't matter. It shouldn't compile it.

Comment: Are you telling it to conform to modern standards? Are you turning on warnings?

Comment: for this site you absolutely have to give a code example.

Comment: Compiler != Linker. While compiling individual translation units (.c. files), the compiler doesn't really care *where* the functions are defined. This is resolved during the linker phase. And if your warnings are turned off, the compiler will also implicitly assume their signatures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the old C there was a thing called implicit function declaration. When a call to an undeclared function appeared it was assumed to be of type `int()`, i.e. a function that takes an unspecified number of parameters and returns an `int`.

```
int main()
{
    foo(); // foo is implicitly declared as `int foo()`
}
```

Since C99 this is illegal. Turn on compiler warnings and use a proper language dialect.

There are more quirks like this from the old age. For instance you could declare function arguments without a type and the type would be implicit `int`:

```
int test(a) // a type is implicitly int
{
    a = 11;

    return a;
}
```

The above doesn't even generate any warnings unless `-pedantic` is used

If you want to go even crazy compile this:

```
double test(a, b)
    int a;
    double b;
{
    a = 11;
    b = 3.14;

    return a + b;
}
```

This is an old way (K&R times) of declaring variables and I didn't find any flags to trigger a warning.

So yeah, old C is strange and finds its way to creep in even today.

Answer (score 0):

C compilers often default to earlier-than-the-last C language standard, and go easy with errors that were historically tolerated by the language.

Your error is one of those that used to be regular legal code 30 years ago.

You want to specifically and explicitly instruct your compiler to be strict with your code by supplying appropriate options. For a reasonably recent build of gcc it would be `-std=c11 -Wall -Werror` or a similar set of options.

The online IDE in question doesn't appear to support passing user-specified options to the underlying compiler, so you're out of luck here. Use your own computer to run a compiler, or find a better online IDE.

Comment: If you look under the editor window of that online compiler you will see a line for passing command line arguments to the compiler.

Comment: @pstrjds The "Command line arguments" line appears to be for the program being debugged, not for the compiler.

Comment: My bad - I just assumed they were for the compiler.